# ejabberd muc creation fails on android with response timeout

Tags: android, ubuntu, ejabberd, smack, multiuserchat

I'm trying to create a muc_room with SMACK api on ejabberd.
after the transaction I get an error:

```
No response received within reply timeout. Timeout was 5000ms (~5s). Used filter: AndFilter: (FromMatchesFilter (full): instantroom2@localhost/pinit, StanzaTypeFilter: Presence).
```

the room is created since it is listed in the output of:

```
ejabberdctl muc_online_rooms localhost
```

when I look into my sql there is only the one room I created locally
also the timeout thing happens when I try to list muc rooms.
is anyone here familiar with this problem?
my ejabberd.yml:

```
  mod_muc_admin: {}
  mod_muc:
    ## host: "conference.@HOST@"
    host: "@HOST@"
    access:
      - allow
    access_admin:
      - allow: admin
    access_create: muc_create
    access_persistent: muc_create
  mod_muc_log: {}
  ## mod_multicast: {}
  mod_offline:
    access_max_user_messages: max_user_offline_messages
  mod_ping: {}
  ## mod_pres_counter:
  ##   count: 5
  ##   interval: 60
```

UPDATE:
I found another strange thing, when I destroy muc_rooms they are not listed in muc_rooms_online but not being removed from mysql DB.
after I restart ejabberd they show up back again.

Comment: Increase reply timeout

Comment: tried that, did'nt help..